# Why textcolor atribute in styles.xml doesn't affect my checkbox?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I'm setting the design of my app in styles.xml. I have this custom_checkbox.xml:

```
<CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/checkboxForActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="10%"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    />
```

And I set the checkbox colors at styles.xml, with `colorControlNormal` and `colorControlActivated`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
```

Also, I have an alertDialog with checkboxes created with:

`final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.CustomDialog)).setTitle("Title here").setMultiChoiceItems(mItems, mSelection, this);`

The colors from the checkboxes were set in the styles.xml, except the textColor atribute.

The thing is: The text in the checkboxes at the alertDialog do not get the color set at the `android:textColor` in the styles.xml. Also, when I erase `android:textColor` atribute from my custom_checkbox, the textColor atribute in AppTheme do not set the color of the text.

Why is that happening? Is textColor the correct atribute at Styles.xml to set the color of this kind of text?

Comment: use `android:color` and see if it works, or set it when you are using the checkbox or dialog.

Comment: 'android:color' did not changed the color's text... I could set the parameter in the custom_checkbox, but I don't know how to set it in the dialog.

Comment: try setting it programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered. `textColorPrimaryDisableOnly` fixed the text in my custom_checkbox, and `textColorAlertDialogListItem` fixes in dialog lists.

Just add these in the styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/white</item>
```